# Make amsbook right

Tags: table-of-contents, abstract, acknowledgements

My LaTeX looks as follows (I omit a lot of `\usepackage`):

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsbook}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\title{\textsc{AAAZZZ}}
\author{LZ}
\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{roman}


\chapter*{Abstract}
The goal of this notes is to describe...


\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I offer my sincerest gratitude to...

\maketitle

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@tocline}
{\hfil}
{\leaders\hbox{\,.\,}\hfil}{}{}
\makeatother
{\large {\tableofcontents}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Section name}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Preliminaries on A}

\chapter{Preliminaries on Z}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that Abstract and Acknowledgements appear before the title page. How to make them appear the title page and before Table of contents?

Comment: Did you try to put the ``\maketitle`` command _before_ the abstract and the acknowledgements?

Comment: Tried now, it fixed my stupid question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Vincent want to convert that comment into an answer?

Comment: @Skillmon yes, done!

Comment: @Vincent My `Table of contents` has only one page, and CHAPTER 1 start exactly after that (and I use`\pagenumbering{arabic}` before `\chapter` begins). But I want it start one page later, still with numbering "1" (not "2"), i.e. `Table of contents` should have a virtual page. Could you also write in your answer?

Comment: Yes! Could you update your MWE so that it can be compiled directly? Some packages are missing.

Comment: Can you say what is "MWE"?

Comment: It's a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?noredirect=1&lq=1). It's just the code you send when you ask your question, but it's a better idea if it can be directly compiled

Comment: OK, I just asked another question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520004/problems-with-page-header-on-table-of-contents about this.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply put the `\maketitle` command before the abstract and the acknowledgements chapters.