# Problems with page header on Table of contents page

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr, header

My LaTeX looks as follows (I omit a lot of `\usepackage` and some fancy settings, e.g. open at odd pages):

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsbook}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase\leftmark}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\title{\textsc{AAAZZZ}}
\author{LZ}
\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{roman}

\maketitle

\chapter*{Abstract}
The goal of this notes is to describe...


\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I offer my sincerest gratitude to...

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@tocline}
{\hfil}
{\leaders\hbox{\,.\,}\hfil}{}{}
\makeatother
{\large {\tableofcontents}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Section name}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Preliminaries on A}

\chapter{Results on Z}

\end{document}
```

My problems are two folds:

> `Table of contents` has only one page, and `CHAPTER 1` start directly after that. But I want it start one page later, still with numbering "1" (not "2"), i.e. `Table of contents` should have a virtual/empty 2nd page (which should be of plain style, no header/footer). How to achieve this?

And:

> If I add more things in Table of contents, then the page header on the 2nd page of Table of contents appears as "Chapter 0. Table of contents" (on the right; the left is the page number "viii", which I want to keep, I would also be satisfied if no header/footer on the 2nd page of Table of contents)? Is there a way to make it as "Table of contents" only?

Comment: Could you add in your code the packages that are necessary to make it compilable? It will be easier to help you if we can compile your code and see exactly what's wrong!

Comment: You could just use [oneside], since you are messing up the odd/even pages anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code template seems to address all of your concerns:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,etoolbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase\leftmark}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\leaders\hbox{\,.\,}\hfil}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\frontmatter

\title{\textsc{AAAZZZ}}
\author{LZ}

\maketitle

\chapter*{Abstract}
The goal of this notes is to describe \ldots

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I offer my sincerest gratitude to \ldots

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Preliminaries on A}

\chapter{Results on Z}

\end{document}
```

Specifically, here are some suggestions:

- Use `\pagestyle{plain}` for the front part of your book (up to just before `\mainmatter`). The `plain` page style sets only the page number in the footer. It would be possible to append this to what `\frontmatter` does and therefore clean up your code a little more.
- Use `\pagestyle{fancy}` for the main part of your book (after `\mainmatter`). It would be possible to append this to what `\mainmatter` does and therefore clean up your code a little more.
- `\cleardoublepage` after `\tableofcontents` should clear the pages sufficiently so there's a blank page left between the end of the ToC and the start of the first chapter (if the ToC is only a single page).
- Using `\pagenumbering{arabic}` resets the page number to 1, so you'll always start the first `\chapter` on page 1 if you have that preceding the first `\chapter`.

Comment: This perfectly fixes my problems. Many thanks!

Comment: I didn't use `etoolbox` but it still works. Could you explain what it's good for?

Comment: @Lao-tzu: `\patchcmd` requires [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). You may not have loaded it explicitly, but perhaps some other package you're loading loads it. You did mention that your code doesn't include all your `\usepackage`s...

Comment: Thanks! I loaded a lot other packages, it should be some other have similar effect.

Comment: The header of my Appendix appears like "Chapter A", is there an easy way to make it as "Appendix A" or just "A"? Preferably it should be a small modification of my above setting of `\fancyhead` for the Appendix chapter only. Sorry to bother you again!

Comment: I mean still keep the text header like "Chapter 1. Preliminaries on A" unchanged, only change the Appendix header to something like "Appendix A. Other examples on Z".

Comment: Just to record that the following code after `\appendix` will suffice: `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\normalsize\chaptername\ 
  \thechapter.\ #1}{}}`